# File added in the file in HttpWebRequest stream is not available to the called service in conext.request.files

Tags: .net, upload, httpwebrequest

//I am new here,so pardon if question not well put.

request is calling the service but file data written in stream is not available a service.

private void UploadBytesHere(byte[] _bytes, CustomObject _object)
        {

```
        string fileName = _object.FileName.ToString();
        var uri = new Uri(Uri.UriSchemeHttp + "://" + Environment.Host + ":" + "/CalledService/Recieving.extension");

        HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        Request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        Request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data" + "---------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString(); ;
        Request.Method = "POST";

        byte[] buffer = _bytes; //file data in Binary format.

        Stream oStream = Request.GetRequestStream();

    //write text writes the byte data into the request stream            
        WriteText("--" +  "---------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + Environment.NewLine, oStream);
        WriteText(@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""fileUpload""; filename=""" + fileName + @"""" +
```

Environment.NewLine, oStream);
            WriteText(@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine, oStream);

```
        oStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); //writing binary file data.
        WriteText(Environment.NewLine, oStream);
        // Output the final closing boundary
        WriteText("--" +  "---------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + "--" + Environment.NewLine, oStream);
        oStream.Close();
        try
        {

            // get the response

    // tried
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
            //tried 
            //using (HttpWebResponse response2 = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse()) { }

            //tried
            NameValueCollection headers = new NameValueCollection();
            headers.Set("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                wc.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
                wc.Headers.Add(headers);
                byte[] responseMessage = wc.UploadData(uri, buffer);
            }

    //Reading the OutPut response
            StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()); //exception comes here.
            string FileIDText = Convert.ToString(rdr.ReadToEnd());
        }
        catch (WebException wex)
        {
            string pageContent = new StreamReader(wex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd().ToString();
    //exception message is, index out of bounds of array. as no file is being available in the 
    //Httpcontext.request.files       
        }



    }

    private static void WriteThisTostream(string input, Stream output)
    {
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
        output.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
```

//Dummy service code.
//Code is also hitting
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {

```
            HttpFileCollection collection;
            HttpPostedFile file;
            int fileLength;
            System.IO.Stream Stream;

            string fileId = "RandomFileName";

            //getting the last file uploaded
            collection = context.Request.Files; //file is missing.
            file = collection[0];           //exception is thrown here.
            fileLength = file.ContentLength;
            byte[] input = new byte[fileLength];
            //initializes the stream
            Stream = file.InputStream;
            //reads the stream 
            Stream.Read(input, 0, fileLength);
            string folderPath = "FolderPath";
            File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(folderPath, fileId + ".bin"), input);
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write(fileId); //returns File name.
```

}

Comment: It's very hard to answer your question. Before you ask, please read about [how to create minimal examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should at least give us the following information: Minimal code sample, your expected result, your actual result (or error you are facing) and a list of things you have tried.

Comment: HI, I tried minimising the code but that's the best i could come up with. problem is code appears to be fine, but i can't understand why still the problem is there. i found a lot of examples in here and tallied my code as well, everything needed is added. but still functionality is not working.